# How to bind non-UI entity with UI entity in Bevy

Tags: rust, game-engine, game-development, bevy, rapier-2d

#### Description

I'm trying to implement trigger logic when the player faced the trigger I should remove the UI element from the screen.

##### Spawning the trigger point

```rust
/// Create a trigger point and when the user faced with
///  it I'll mark the tutorial as `in-progress` and
///  remove it when the collision between tutorial
///  and player is stopped
commands
  .insert(Sensor(true))
  .insert(Collider::cuboid(8.0, 8.0))
  .insert(ActiveEvents::COLLISION_EVENTS)
  .insert_bundle(SpriteBundle {
    sprite: Sprite {
      color: Color::rgb(0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
      custom_size: Some(Vec2::new(16.0, 16.0)),
      ..Default::default()
    },
    transform: *tutorial_transform,
    ..Default::default()
  })

  // Tutorial is a component which I'll filter as `tutorial_entity`
  .insert(Tutorial);
```

##### Create a UI

```rust
commands
  .spawn_bundle(NodeBundle {
    ///
  })

  /// Trying to bind UI element with `Tutorial` entity
  ///  to remove it from the screen when the user faced with collider
  .insert(Parent(tutorial_entity))
```

##### When the user faced collision

```rust
// I want to despawn all children UI elements that are linked with this non-UI element
commands.entity(tutorial_entity).despawn_recursive()
```

##### Error

I've got an error and no UI on the screen at all

```bash
Styled child in a non-UI entity hierarchy. You are using an entity with UI components as a child of an entity without UI components, results may be unexpected
```

#### Question

Do you know how to link a non-UI element with a UI element to remove the non-UI element and remove all linked UI elements with it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its still relevant but you could always just create a separate UI entity and add your own reference component.
I guess the for structurings sake i would create ( for example ) a UILinkComponent(pub Entity) and attach it to the world entity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you shouldn't use `Parent` for that kind of relationship. The hierarchy is typically used for spatial relationships.

You should instead create a new component that stores the other `Entity`. You can still destroy it in the same way, but this way it isn't part of the hierarchy so the other UI elements don't get confused.